# Equivalent of R's <<- in C++: extern for local variables

Tags: c++, r, extern

I have defined a variable locally to a function in C++, but would like to have it accessible to another C++ function contained in a separate file.

In R, <<- allows local variables to be accessed globally by copying it.

Is there an equivalent to <<- in C++ that will allow me to call local variables (that otherwise is not defined globally) via the extern declaration in another C++ file?

Would the code below be OK and work as expected?

For example, to access y:

```
### File 1.cpp ###
void func() {
    const std::vector x
    int y = x.size()
}

### File 2.cpp ###
extern int y 
y // Call y somewhere else within program
```

Comment: You have a variable that *must* be local and you want to access it from another function in another file? This sounds like the epitome of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You want a variable to be local and yet you want it to be global. The solution seems evident.

Comment: I think there's no equivalent. But, are you using a class in c++? Otherwise you may want to manually create a global variable.

Comment: @DeiDei My comfort is in R but I am using C++ for speed. I am not a native C++ programmer. Could you elaborate on the "solution"?

Comment: Does the function where the local variable is declared interact with the other function? Does it call it? Could you pass the local variable to it? Are they part of the same class?

Comment: Why do you want to reproduce in C++ something which is often considered a design flaw in R?

Comment: @Jay No, I am not using a class. I could see about making the variable global, which would allow extern declaration. I think I will try that.

Comment: Pop quiz: Given your `y` variable declared and defined inside `func()` with automatic storage duration, how many `int` objects exist as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, a function cannot leak declarations into enclosing scopes. The closest thing you can do is this:

```
void f() {
    extern int x;
}
```

This causes `x` to refer to a global variable that is defined somewhere else in the program. Another function in another translation unit, containing the same declaration, could then refer to the same variable. However, neither declaration *defines* the variable, and you must supply a definition at global scope in order for the program to link.

If it's a global variable you need, you should define a global variable. However, mutable global state often makes programs harder to reason about, so it's usually better to avoid it whenever possible. Typically, you'll want to structure your program so that two functions communicate with each other through the function call mechanism whenever possible (passing information in function parameters), or, at worst, share mutable state encapsulated inside a class, so that it can't leak outside the class.

Comment: Thanks! I've added what I think you are proposing to my question post. Am correct in interpreting your response so that the two files may be successfully linked?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips I can't answer syntax questions in the comments section. You should post a new question.